# "npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory" - only happens on 1 computer

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm using a Windows 10 machine for development at home, a Windows 10 machine for development at work, and an Ubuntu 1604 server for production....

When I run "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up" it always works fine on my Windows 10 development machine at home, but when I run the same command on my Windows 10 machine at work it always throws the error...

```
database | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
database | npm ERR! code ENOENT
database | npm ERR! errno -2
database | npm ERR! syscall open
database | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
database | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
database | npm ERR! enoent
database |
database | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
database | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-17T16_28_12_239Z-debug.log
```

I'm using the exact same code, both on a windows 10 OS! I started using Docker specifically to avoid issues like this and its driving me crazy.

Does anyone know what may be happening???

Dockerfile for my Node app...

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Bundle app source into container
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml file...

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: database
    build: .
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4
```

and docker-compose.dev.yml file for running in development....

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: ["npm", "start"]
  mongo:
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: I may have fixed it. I set Docker back to factory defaults in the settings, and used v.10.15.0 for node in my Dockerfile instead of 10, and then the next time I ran "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up" a docker dialogue popped up and asked for Docker to access the C drive. After I gave it permission then it started the containers without a problem

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem when running my "docker-compose up" command from WSL bash.
Sharing drive c to Docker and launching via Power Shell fixed my issue.

Comment: This is not a question, more of a comment, unless you add a solution.